# Why is my implementation of "map" processing elements in reverse order?

Tags: ocaml

This is my implementation of `map`:

```ml
let rec map f lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: tl -> f hd :: map f tl
```

I tried to run it like this:

```ml
(* Print the given int, then return the given int. *)
let print_id n =
    print_int n;
    print_newline ();
    n

let () = ignore (map print_id [1; 2; 3])
```

Although `map print_id [1; 2; 3]` returns `[1; 2; 3]`, the code above prints:

```
3
2
1
```

It seems that the list is being processed in reverse order! What is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OCaml doesn't guarantee an order for evaluation of an expression. So this expression:

```
f hd :: map f tl
```

is permitted to evaluate the call to `map` before the call to `f`.

You  can use `let` to guarantee an evaluation order:

```
let x = f hd in
x :: map f tl
```

Comment: To supplement Jeffrey’s answer: in practice, current-day OCaml achieves a right-to-left evaluation order in most contexts (not sure if there are counter-examples), but of course that’s not guaranteed. In the close future, when “tail recursion modulo constructors” makes its way into the language ([it just got merged!](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/9760)), the evaluation order of this specific example may become left-to-right—though you’ll have to enable the optimization explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

With following reduction order for the function `map`, things will be clear enough to you hopefully.

```
map print_id [1; 2; 3]
print_id 1 :: map print_id [2; 3]
print_id 1 :: print_id 2 :: map print_id [3]
print_id 1 :: print_id 2 :: print_id 3 :: map print_id []
print_id 1 :: print_id 2 :: print_id 3 :: []      (* print_id 3, prints 3 and returns 3 *)
print_id 1 :: print_id 2 :: 3 :: []               (* print_id 2, prints 2 and returns 2 *)        
print_id 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: []                        (* print_id 1, prints 1 and returns 1 *)
1 :: 2 :: 3 :: []                                 (* List Construction yields [1; 2; 3] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

One more point, in addition to the excellent answers already offered. The standard library implements both `List.map` and [*`List.iter`*](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALiter). The latter has the type `('a -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit` and is typically used when side effects are the point of iterating over a list, rather than constructing a new list.

You can trivially implement this yourself. It has the benefit of making evaluation order explicitly what you want, and it's naturally tail-recursive.

```
let rec iter f = function
  | [] -> ()
  | hd::tl -> f hd; iter f tl
```